# applicationContext xml file outside of src folder

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to place applicationContext.xml into WEB-INF folder? I am specific to WEB-INF folder because I know that it can be placed into WEB-INF\classes folder.

As per the requirement, Clients should be able to configure applicationContext.xml according to their setup.
There is another option I thought of importing xml configuration files from WEB-INF folder to applicationContext.xml. But I didn't tried it yet and not sure how feasible it is.

Comment: What kind of configuration? Are they allowed to add/remove beans in XML or just change some values like URL addresses, passwords, etc.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz ApplicationContext has camel routes which client will be changing according his needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your requirement point of view, there is absolutely no difference between putting it in the WEB-INF or in WEB-INF/classes directory: Either way it needs to be accessed from the exploded WAR/EAR after deployment, which may not be possible if your app server don't explode it (ie, JBoss can work directly with the WAR).

IMO, the solution for you is to stop using the WebApplicationContext implementation. Use DefaultListableBeanFactory which should be initialized in a ServletContextListener, reading the configuration file manually. That way you can obtain the path to the applicationContextFile from the ApplicationServer environment (using JNDI or whatever method suits you), so it can be places anywhere in the machine where the Application Server resides.

At least that's what we did, for the very same reason you have.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this, but the classpath is a pretty logical place to put them.

In your web.xml, in the  definition for "contextConfigLocation", just add /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml to the  section.

Answer (score 1):

If you add  this in the web.xml then you can access the applicationContext

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>
       /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
       </param-value>
</context-param>
```